# custom listview search displaying wrong results

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

In my app, I am fetching data from sqlite and showing the data in a list view. Now,I want to filter the list view. For this, I had implemented a search widget but, it is giving incorrect results. Here's my code:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"/>
```

i have this code in my onCreateOptionsMenu

```
....
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(this.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
            .getActionView();

    if (null != searchView) {

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            // default adapter
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }
    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

....
```

my adapter code is

```
public class AmbulanceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

Context context;
String[] namesArray, areasArray, contactsArray;

public AmbulanceAdapter(Context c, String[] Names,
        String[] Areas, String[] Contacts){ 
    super(c, R.layout.row_ambulance, R.id.nametv, Names);
    this.context = c;
    this.namesArray = Names; 
    this.areasArray = Areas;
    this.contactsArray = Contacts;
}

class viewHolder {
    TextView nametv, areatv, contacttv;  

    public viewHolder(View v) {

        nametv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nametv);
        areatv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.areatv);
        contacttv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contacttv);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    viewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_ambulance, parent, false);

        holder = new viewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (viewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.nametv.setText(namesArray[position]);
    holder.areatv.setText(areasArray[position]);
    holder.contacttv.setText(contactsArray[position]);

    return row;
}
```

}

But am getting wrong search results, where have i gone wrong ?

Comment: What is wrong with your results? Are they not filtered? Did you check that your onQuery… methods were getting called? Also, if you're using a DB, why are you using an ArrayAdapter rather than a CursorAdapter?

Comment: it is filtering but am getting incorrect results

Comment: what is incorrect with your results?

Comment: same problem
it filtered but i am clicking the item i am showing the data in popup data in pop was previous data was coming
Ebiz(EIS)